# Font detection browser add-on

Tags: css, font-face

I am very pleased with the Web Developer Toolbar and Colorzilla add-on. I like how I can use those features to easily detect the HTML structure and colors used in web pages. But in my search for a good CSS font detection tool, I haven't come across anything that works in a similar way. Does anyone know of something out there that I have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a tool called [WhatFont](http://chengyinliu.com/whatfont.html) for this purpose

[image]

It shows various information about the font used in each DOM element, such as font family, color, size and even where the `@font-face` files are served from. It is available in the form of a [bookmarklet](http://chengyinliu.com/whatfont.html#whatfont-install-bookmarklet) or a [Chrome add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm).